# Median of a Probability Density Function

Tags: probability, density-function, median

I am currently doing my homework and for one of the questions, it asks me to find the median of the random variable X with the probability density function:
$f(x) = [1/x^2]$ with interval $[1, \infty]$. I keep getting 2 while the textbook says 1/2.

My interval for the integration is [1,m] and i'm solving for m?

Edit: My Work:
$\int ^m _1 (1/x^2) dx = -x^-1 + c$ 
and then I plug in m and 1 which then becomes:$(-(1/m)) - (-1/1) = 1/2$ which then i solved to get m=2?

Comment: Can you show us your work?

Comment: I think your answer is fine. $1/2$ does not even make sense if the density is supported on $[1, \infty)$.

Comment: So i guess the consensus is that my textbook is wrong. That's good! I thought I was losing brain cells for a sec there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The median satisfies

$$\int_1^m f(x) dx = \frac{1}{2}$$

So then

$$\int_1^m f(x) dx = \int_1^m \frac{1}{x^2} dx = \frac{-1}{x} \Biggr \vert_{x=1}^{x=m} = \frac{-1}{m} - \frac{-1}{1} = 1 - \frac{1}{m} = \frac{1}{2}$$

$$\implies m = 2$$

If you check your result and calculate $\operatorname{P}(X \le 2)$, then you get

$$\int_1^2 f(x) dx = \int_1^2 \frac{1}{x^2} dx = \frac{-1}{x} \Biggr \vert_{x=1}^{x=2} = \frac{-1}{2} - \frac{-1}{1} = 1 - \frac{1}{2} = \frac{1}{2}$$

So most likely the answer on your textbook is wrong (if I did everything correctly).

Comment: I also tried doing the "opposite" and calculating $$\int_m^\infty \frac{1}{x^2} dx = \int_2^\infty \frac{1}{x^2} dx = -\frac{1}{x} \Biggr \vert_{2}^{\infty} = \frac{1}{2}$$ So I am very certain that the answer in indeed $m = 2$, also $m=\frac{1}{2}$ cannot be an answer as it is not in the domain of the PDF

Comment: That's what I thought as well. Ok that's good. For a moment, I thought I possessed 0 brain cells after studying non-stop for 2 days.

Comment: lol not the only one